# Running a casper.js script from cron

Tags: linux, cron, casperjs

I'm trying to run a casper.js script via cron. Everything works fine when I run the script manually, but when I run it via cron I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/bin/casperjs", line 46, in <module>
   status = subprocess.call(CASPER_COMMAND)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 480, in call
   return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 633, in __init__
   errread, errwrite)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1139, in _execute_child
   raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

My crontab entry is:

`30 9 * * * /usr/local/bin/casperjs lib/fsaupload.js arg1 arg2 arg3`

I've also tried

`30 9 * * * python /usr/local/bin/casperjs lib/fsaupload.js arg1 arg2 arg3`

Which gives me the same result. Any ideas? I'm guessing it might be a `path` issue, but no idea where to go from here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably use an absolute path to your casper script, something like:

```
30 9 * * * /usr/local/bin/casperjs /absolute/path/to/lib/fsaupload.js arg1 arg2 arg3
```

My two cents.

**Edit:**

Okay, it was a bit silly. You can also set a custom path to the `phantomjs` executable by setting the `PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE` environment variable:

```
$ export PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE="/path/to/phantomjs"
```

Then run your script as usual:

```
/usr/local/bin/casperjs /absolute/path/to/lib/fsaupload.js arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Hint: If your crontab runs as another user, check that it has access to the phantomjs path.

Hope it helps (and works).

**Edit again**

Wait, the stack trace you get says you're using an old version of CasperJS (eg. the `subprocess` module is no more used). Try with a more recent version :)

Comment: Hmmmm... Still nothing. I still get the same error. I've even tried specifying the full path to Python too, but still no dice. Any ideas?

Comment: What if you're trying to run with --web-security=no , this should work correct?

Answer (score 3):

This is an older question, but still relevant - I just spent 4 hours trying to resolve this, without finding a direct solution.  What was happening for me was exactly the same, I could run the casper.js script from the shell command line, but not via a cron job.  As alluded to by NiKo, but not spelled out clearly enough for **me** to *get*, casper needs to know where Phantomjs is in order to work.

I created a shell script, cron_wrap.sh, which contains the path to the Phantomjs bin directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/src/phantomjs/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
/usr/local/bin/casperjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true /srv/www/apps/myscript.js
```

Make your .sh executable, now you can add the script to cron:

```
00 09 * * * /srv/www/apps/myscript.js
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an older, older question, but I was dealing with this for a while, too. I could no longer restart Apache (for Django) via cron (talk about downtime) and this ended up being the issue. Instead of the wrapper script like Jesse Q used, I just added my casperjs/phantom-augmented PATH to the TOP of my crontab

```
PATH=/usr/local/src/phantomjs/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
/usr/local/bin/casperjs
```

and it now works. You can check your cron environment by writing to a file in crontab like so:

```
* * * * * env > ~/cronenv
```

just vim into it to see what your current cron PATH is. Nice for debugging this issue.