# Run a php file contain javascript from cron job

Tags: javascript, php, curl, cron, crontrigger

I tried many online methods people have suggested and still not reached a solution

i need to run a php file that contain javascript from cronjob

For now, I can not do it through PHP

If anyone has an idea I'd love to read

Comment: what can javascript do in a cronjob ? Send an ajax request back to tghe server

Comment: Can you run that script in shell, without providing any input to it interactively? If yes, then with appropriate settings you can use cron, else not.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to trigger it through a browser.  Get a computer to open the URL via the cron tab (or some other timed device... I know you can do it through Automator/AppleScript on a Mac).

Answer (score 0):

How I do it: I split the job in to tasks.

**Task 1: Execute Javascript**

Javascript would require a browser to run. In this respect you can try casperjs/phantomjs. You can create a a cronjob for this easily. Please check: [Running a casper.js script from cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705418/running-a-casper-js-script-from-cron)

**Task 2: Deliver results to PHP**

I assume that you take the results of the JS and use it in the PHP. So JSON can do the job. At the end of the first task output to a file. In this task, read it using file_get_contents.

**Task 3: PHP Cron**

It is obvious :)

Sure that there are better, easier and simpler solutions. I am a newbie also here, but this method all my problems for a similar work.